# How can I get a random image on my lockscreen?

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, lock-screens, images

Could you recommend me a simple solution to set a random image for my lockscreen?

I have the stock Samsung launcher, stock ICS rom and I don't want to install any custom launcher. I'm just looking for an app to switch the image every few hours.

Comment: Not sure why the Close vote. This seems like a reasonable and on-topic question to me.

Comment: There are lots of background switchers on Google Play. Are they not switching the lock screen image too?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a live wallpaper that downloads new images periodicaly.
This one has a lot of built in image sites (like national geographic, nasa, ...):

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.dngames.picofday

It looks like a normal wallpaper and is battery friendly.
The only problem I see is that most of the built in sources update once per day not every few hours, but you can define your own source of images.

You can also try searching for other similar solutions. I think the livewallpaper way is the best beacuse it has a lot less issues with lockscreens (you just choose the live wallpaper as the lockscreen wallpaper and it should leave the normal background intact.

Comment: I prefer to use images from SD card.

Comment: Not to mention he has already mentioned that he doesn't want to change the wallpaper; only the lock screen. It's not possible with the current applications on Google Play and his additional requirements peppered throughout the comments sections.

Comment: On both of my Samsung phones, changing the walpaper brings up a menu with 3 options: "home", "lock" and "home and lock". You can only change the lockscreen wallpaper to the livewallpaper which changes images and have whatever you wish on the home wallpaper.

Answer (score 0):

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.j4velin.wallpaperChanger

From Google Play:

> Change your wallpaper with one click or automatically every X minutes!
>   This app allows you to quickly change your wallpaper with one single click on a widget!
>   Additionally, you can enable a timer to automatically change your wallpaper on a predefined time.
>   Images can easily be added to the rotation list by using the Android Gallery app or a file manager like FileExpert.
>   This app is optimized for battery life & performence, so it might take some seconds to actually change the wallpaper after a click on the widget!
>   Features:

- easily add images or even folders through the Android gallery & other file managers
- change wallpaper with a timer, on each lockscreen unlock or through a customizable widget
- 3 widgets: change to next wallpaper in rotation list, select the wallpaper you want to see or change the album with one click
- ordered rotation or random wallpaper
- very low memory and battery consumption: doesnt need any background services running and is not implemented live wallpaper
- no ads

Comment: Discription clearly explains that this is a wallpaper changer. No use for lockscreen.

Comment: It works on both my OG Droid and my GNex. Please give it a try and let us know if it does not work for your phone somehow...

Comment: Maybe works, although I don't want to change the normal wallpaper, just for the lockscreen. Same as on Kindle Fire.

Comment: The only other way is to program something or root and get a ROM that supports what you want. Why the down-vote? I [actually answered](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/28035/6217) your [actual question](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/27360/how-can-i-get-a-random-image-on-my-lockscreen).