# How to change lock screen on a phone like it is on a Kindle Fire?

Tags: lock-screens, amazon-kindle-fire

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I get a random image on my lockscreen?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/27360/how-can-i-get-a-random-image-on-my-lockscreen)

Everytime the user turns on the Kindle Fire, the lockscreen of the device presents a different background. (Of course it cycles trough a list of pictures and later it repeats itself) I'd like to achieve this behaviour on my phone. I'm not interested in the way of the unlock. I just want that custom pictures appear in the background of the lockscreen if I turn on the screen.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean?  are you talking about a live wallpaper that cycles through different err wallpapers? I do not think it can be done, AFAIK, Lockscreens are meant to be "static" in that sense of a word, maybe there's third party apps on the play store that can enhance the existing lock screen?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need root access to change lock screen of your phone. Kindle Fire's type of lock screen is called `Sliding Tab` or `Slider`. I'm not sure if it's possible to use exactly the same lock screen but you can experiment with applications on [Play Store](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=lockscreen+slider&c=apps).

Comment: Not exactly what I wanted to know. Updated the question to make it clear.